# Interfacing 32-bit and 64-bit code with VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, com, compatibility, 32bit-64bit

I have a 64-bit project(which has to be 64-bit as it is an Outlook 2010/64 bit addin) that needs to interface with another Dll of mine, whose job it is to scrape file metadata out of files using the windows Shell32 dll. Now, as you may of guessed, this is posing compatibility problems as I am crossing that 64/32 bit boundary.

I read an article (ok skimmed it, whatever) and from what I understand, it suggested that I use COM as an intermediary and to bridge this gap. So, My question is, can I build a shim DLL in say VB6 (i know, i know) that would act as my com reference and pass the calls on to my 32-bit dll from my 64-bit addin? Can I do this? Has anyone done this? and most importantly, can someone SHOW me how to do this.

Do I create a VB6 COM Dll, reference my .NET assembly and pass all Public functions out via a similar interface, then reference the VB6 dll in my 64-bit addin? is it just that easy?

Thanks for the sanity check..

Andrew

Comment: Why not build your other DLL in both 32-bit and 64-bit flavors and load the correct one accordingly?

Comment: I do know that when I call COM Vb6 dll's from code compiled for AnyCPU, it throws out an exception. Not sure if it applies for 64bit as well.  It does work when compiled to x86